How to determine that an element has finished "printing" on the screen?
There is a chat in which the desired element is “printed” on the screen using the type of keyboard input (obviously using JavaScript).
How, in this case, can one determine that this text has already finished being “printed” and is ready to do something with it?
I know that this element is p class="answer". There are several such elements on the page, but only the last of them is “printed” during output.

Here's how I solved this issue in Java.
I ask that you put a # sign at the end of your chat reply.
Then I gave the initial time for the chat to start typing the answer and I find that "p" element.
And here is what remains to be done to mean that the chat has finished “printing”:
while(true) {
  text= pTag.getText();
  if(text.endsWith("#")) {
    break;
  } else {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    continue;
  }
}

